# to retrieve servletcontext path

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using Netbeans 7 for developing my web project.I need to store images received from client side to web/images folder.

```
String location = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");
```

If i use this code i get location

```
C:\Users\Computer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\build\web\images
```

But i need to store in

```
 C:\Users\Computer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\web\images
```

i need to later show those images in my jsp page so those images must be in web\images folder isnt it???....

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary for you to store them in the deployment folder?  If people are uploading pictures it is usually a better practice to store them in a database. (If they are small)  Or in a directory separate from  the deployment. Storing them in the deployment will cause them to be erased every time you need to redeploy.  If you go with the route I am suggesting you will need to write a simple servlet that is able to re-serve the images that were submitted by your client from where ever you are storing them.

If you are using tomcat you can store the files where ever you like.  Then create a filter that passes all requests to a defined url on to a specific directory on your host by adding the following to your server.xml file:

```
<Context path="/clientrequestpath/images" docBase="/serverpath/images/" />
```

Where path is the request URL that is sent by the browser and docBase is where you store the images locally on your host.  You don't need to write a servlet in this case, just add the image name stored in the database to the  tag in your jsp when it is sent to the client, then the client will automatically request the image files.

Comment: so where should i store it then.I am storing only iamge location in database.If i need to get location of folder from my servlet without giving relative location like

    C:\Users\Computer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\web\images
how would i achieve it.???

Comment: You will have to set the docBase path to absolute path where ever you are storing the images. Don't store the location of the folder in the database, only the name of the image.